# Is there a way to compute the area of $\mathbb{S}^n$ using differential forms?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to calculate the surface area of an n-dimensional sphere $\mathbb{S}^n\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by means of a differential form. For let $$\omega=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-1}x^{i}dx^{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{dx^{i}}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{n+1}$$ be the volume form of the sphere and take the parameterization $F:[0,\pi]^{n-1}\times[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{S}^n$ where $$F(y^1,\dots,y^n)=(z^1,\dots,z^n,z^{n+1}) $$

and

$$
\begin{align}
z^1&=\cos y^1 \\
z^2&=\sin y^1\cos y^2 \\
z^3&=\sin y^1\sin y^2\cos y^3\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
 z^n&=\sin y^1\cdots\sin y^{n-1}\cos y^n\\
z^{n+1}&=\sin y^1\cdots\sin y^{n-1}\sin y^n\\
\end{align}
$$

So I've tried to compute $F^{*}\omega$ in order to compute $\int F^{*}\omega$ , but the computations began to turn out very complicated. Can anyone help me with such calculations? Is there a easier way to do these computations ?

Comment: Yes, the easier way is to use Stokes's Theorem. Either way, you're going to need an inductive approach, as both the area of $S^{n-1}$ and the volume of $D^n$ involve powers of $\pi$ and factorials.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you make a sketch? Because I've tried to find some patterns in order to use inductive arguments, but I didn't find a smart way to do so.

Comment: There are lots and lots of posts here on this. Just search for volume of n-ball. The most efficient way to approach this is to write $$\text{vol}(D^n) = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\text{vol}\big(D^{n-2}(\sqrt{1-r^2})\big)r\,dr\,d\theta = \text{vol}(D^{n-2})\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (1-r^2)^{(n-2)/2}r\,dr\,d\theta.$$

Comment: Maybe you find this [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098098/calculating-surface-area-using-differential-forms/4451636?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C73.9843#4451636)